# How can we avoid the extra bezier curve line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cgcontextref

Can we avoid the extra bezier curve line after the last point in Bezier graph? Is there any property for that?

[image: Please check the screenshot]

We need just end-end curve graph, no extra curve. Please share the solutions/suggestion. Update: Please check the code below,

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIBezierPath *line = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
NSValue *value = points[0];
CGPoint p1 = [value CGPointValue];
[line moveToPoint:p1];if (points.count == 2) {
    value = points[1];
    CGPoint p2 = [value CGPointValue];
    [line addLineToPoint:p2];
    return line;
}

for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < points.count; i++) {
    value = points[i];
    CGPoint p2 = [value CGPointValue];

    CGPoint midPoint = midPointForPoints(p1, p2);
    [line addQuadCurveToPoint:midPoint controlPoint:controlPointForPoints(midPoint, p1)];
    [line addQuadCurveToPoint:p2 controlPoint:controlPointForPoints(midPoint, p2)];

    p1 = p2;
}
 CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    pathLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    pathLayer.path = line.CGPath;
    pathLayer.strokeColor = self.color.CGColor;
    pathLayer.fillColor = nil;
    pathLayer.opacity = self.lineAlpha;
    pathLayer.lineWidth = self.lineWidth;
    pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
    pathLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
 [self.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];}


static CGPoint midPointForPoints(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2) {
return CGPointMake((p1.x + p2.x) / 2, (p1.y + p2.y) / 2);}
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you share some code and explain more what you exactly need, you want the graph to just end after the last orange point ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @HusseinDimessi Yes I need a graph just end of the last orange point. I will share the code.

Comment: @HusseinDimessi Please check the added code. Thanks!

Comment: I m not 100% sure but I think if you change the for loop to iterate to just (points.count - 1) instead of points.count it will work

Comment: @HusseinDimessi I tried with (points.count - )1 but it's not working.

Comment: Any Other solutions?

Comment: just a second I ll review your code

Comment: Hi @HusseinDimessi I found it. Actually (points.count - 1) works fine. Since it's a dynamic list, In my case, reducing number should be the dynamic  (i.e points.count - 4 or points.count - 5). It's just small mistake. Thanks for your help.

Comment: good to hear : )